# How to not to repeat background specs with multiple responsive backgrounds

Tags: css, sass, background-image, responsive

here's the current code:

```
.description-1-section{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #464646 30.75%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 100%), url('../images/fondo-1-s.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: $white;

  @include mq($medium-up){
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #464646 30.75%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 100%), url('../images/fondo-1-m.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

  @include mq($medium-aux-up){
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #464646 30.75%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 100%), url('../images/fondo-1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

I've found out that is using multiple bgs (in this case a gradient + an image), when updating some value for breakpoints purposes, it seems I must repeat the accessory directives (`background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;`).

Is there a way to avoid such repetions in this use case?

Comment: Don't use the shorthand `background:` would probably a good start as it overwrites other bg properties. Use bg image instead.

Comment: I cannot find any useful info about how to set multiple backgrounds without the shorthand.

Comment: `background-image: url(1), url(2);` - seems pretty simple.

Comment: mmm, great! :) You should post it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the shorthand `background` **resets** the implicit properties not listed separately.

> The background shorthand CSS property sets all background style properties at once, such as color, image, origin and size, or repeat method.
>
> <sup>[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)</sup>

I'd recommend using simply `background-image` instead

```
background-image: 
  linear-gradient(0deg, #464646 30.75%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 100%),
  url('../images/fondo-1-s.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS variables and put background-size and repeat inside the shorthand too. You will also avoid repeating the gradient:

```
.description-1-section{
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #464646 30.75%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 100%), var(--im,url('../images/fondo-1-s.jpg')) center/cover no-repeat;
  color: $white;

  @include mq($medium-up){
    --im: url('../images/fondo-1-m.jpg');
  }

  @include mq($medium-aux-up){
    --im: url('../images/fondo-1.jpg');
  }
}
```

A working example to test:

```css
.description-1-section{
  background: 
   linear-gradient(0deg, #464646 30.75%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0) 100%), 
   var(--im,url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/600/200')) center/cover no-repeat;
  height:50px;
}
.md{
    --im: url('https://picsum.photos/id/10/600/200');
  }

.ml{
    --im:url('https://picsum.photos/id/12/600/200');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="description-1-section">

</div>
<div class="description-1-section md">

</div>
<div class="description-1-section ml">

</div>
```

Comment: this is interesting, thank you. It would have some crossbrowser issue though, if not using some polyfill.

Comment: @LucaReghellin you will only have issue with IE like usual: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: It's enough to be an issue for my client.

Comment: @LucaReghellin by the way, you are using SASS so consider variables